# How to remove background transparency in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I would like to display ulSList as popup. The problem is that it's background is transparent in IE7.

```
<a class="uLink" href="#" id="aShare">SHARE</a>

<ul id="ulSList" style="display: block; >    
<li><a href="#email.html">Email</a></li>
<li><a href="#facebook.html">Facebook</a></li>
```

How can I remove background transparency in IE7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<a class="uLink" href="#" id="aShare">SHARE</a>

<ul id="ulSList" style="display: block; background-color: white;">    
<li><a href="#email.html">Email</a></li>
<li><a href="#facebook.html">Facebook</a></li>
```

Comment: white background is transparent. i need to remove transparency.

Comment: If it's not transparent, what color do you want it to be?

Comment: solid black ; no partial color

Comment: So then use `background-color: black;` - I'm not sure what partial color means.